# Executing DataBinding Prior to Initial OnResume of Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding, activity-lifecycle

I have setup data binding with some custom attributes in my Application. The generated classes look correct and I can even see where the default values are bounded to the attributes in the generated binding classes in the `executeBindings` method. I need to access these custom attributes in the initial `OnResume` of an Activity when it's first created and found that the bindings execute **AFTER** that lifecycle method is called. So when I check initially, the attribute is null. Obviously on subsequent `OnResume` calls after an `OnPause` everything works fine. Is there a way to force the initial binding to happen prior to my initial check in `OnResume`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can call [`executePendingBindings()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding.html#executePendingBindings()) on the binding.

> Evaluates the pending bindings, updating any Views that have expressions bound to modified variables. This must be run on the UI thread.